# Overloading builtin functions like Write-Verbose

Tags: oop, powershell

I just learned the benefit of using `Write-Verbose` & `Write-Debug` over my own `Write-Log` function, which you can find below:

```
Function Write-Log 
{
    param($logType, $logString, $logFile, [switch]$newLine)

    $time = get-date -Format "HH:mm:ss"
    $date = get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $line = "[${date}][${time}][$logType] ${logString}"

    if ($logFile) 
    {
        $retryDelay = 0.5; 
        $maxRetries = 10; 
        $retries = 0;

        while($retries -lt $maxRetries) 
        {
            try 
            {
                $line | out-file -Encoding utf8 -Append $logFile
                break; 
            } 
            catch 
            {
                ++$retries;
                Sleep $retryDelay; 
            }
        }
    }

    if ($logType -eq 'INFO') 
    {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Green $line 
    } 
    elseif ($logType -eq 'WARN') 
    {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $line
    } 
    elseif ($logType -eq 'ERROR') 
    {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Red $line
    }

    if ($newLine -eq $true)
    {
        write-host 
    }
}
```

This helps to me keep my scripts output as little cluttered as possible and includes a timestamp which is handy when it comes to debugging.

**Question**

Is there a way to overload `Write-Verbose` so it behaves in the following way?

```
PS > Write-Verbose -Message 'I am a verbose message!' 

[2016-02-25][07:44:36] VERBOSE: I am a verbose message!
```

**Edit**

I have found the following, which unfortunately isn't honoring the `$VerbosePreference` variable:

```
$VerbosePreference = "SilentlyContinue"

Function Private:Write-Verbose ($Message) 
{
    $time = get-date -Format "HH:mm:ss"
    $date = get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $line = "[${date}][${time}] "

    Write-Host $line -NoNewline 

    &{Write-Verbose -Message $Message}

}

Write-Verbose -Message "Test"
```

The above will just output the date and timestamp, without the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write-Verbose resides within Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility , so this is not possible afaik; without manipulating and change built-in behavior in Powershell (which should be avoided).

You could either create your own "Write-Verbose" function in your script/session scope; which would output the desired result (using cmdletbinding()); or live with an output message such as "VERBOSE: [2016-02-25][07:44:36] Your log message" (rely on the default behavior of write-verbose).

I'd recommend the latter unless you have some funky output requirements for your host.

If you go on and create your own Write-Verbose function, you should use the  [cmdletbinding()] before your params; as this enables default parameters/switches to be passed to your functions(such as -verbose / -information, -debug etc). 
For more information about cmdletbinding and parameter-binding see:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/07/weekend-scripter-cmdletbinding-attribute-simplifies-powershell-functions/

https://posh2scripting.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/what-is-cmdletbinding/

Last thing; it's not recommended of using Write-host directly in your scripts as this messes with default stream redirects (etc). I would highly suggest on using Write-Verbose, Write-Debug, Write-information, Write-Output cmdlets if you're printing information to streams.

More information for not using Write-host can be found on:

http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/donjones/archive/2012/04/06/2012-scripting-games-commentary-stop-using-write-host.aspx

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is Kind of a follow-up question so I am adding it here: How can I then write the verbose-Output-stream to a file? `Write-Verbose "something" | Out-File -Filepath "Log.txt"` doesn't store anything.

Comment: Well I am Aware that I can use `4>>` to Redirect verbose streams but this will then hide the output from the console.

Comment: `*>` / `*>>` will redirect all streams (except host; as that's not really a stream but rather just an output to the console).  Full list of streams here: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/297055/capture-warning-verbose-debug-and-host-output-via-alternate-streams

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @CmdrTchort on the answer to this question.

This answer's provided to give an implementation of a custom implementation of `Write-Verbose` which could be used instead (i.e. by making calls to `Write-CustomVerbose` instead of `Write-Verbose`.  Obviously this won't affect any existing code or code in referenced libraries which still use `Write-Verbose`.

```
function Write-CustomVerbose {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='UseTimestamp')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [string]$Message
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName='UseTimestamp')]
        [string]$TimestampFormat = ((Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern)
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName='UseTimestamp')]
        [switch]$UseLocalTime #defaults to UTC
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName='DoNotUseTimestamp')]
        [switch]$ExcludeTimestamp #defaults to include the timestamp (as that's why we're using this function over the standard write-verbose

    )
    begin {
        [string]$FormattedMessage = '{0}'
        if(-not $ExcludeTimestamp.IsPresent) {
            $FormattedMessage = "{1:$TimestampFormat}: $FormattedMessage"
        }
    }
    process {
        #get the time here rather than in begin as we want it to be accurate per message from pipeline
        [DateTime]$Now = Get-Date
        if(-not $UseLocalTime.IsPresent){$Now = $Now.ToUniversalTime()}
        #output the results
        write-verbose ($FormattedMessage -f $Message, $Now)
    }
}
```

Example Usage: `1..1000 | Write-CustomVerbose -Verbose -UseLocalTime -TimestampFormat 'HH:mm'`

---

**Update**

Here's a slightly more advanced version allowing you to hijack all streams at once:

```
function Write-Custom {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='UseTimestamp')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [PSCustomObject]$InputObject
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName='UseTimestamp')]
        [string]$TimestampFormat = ((Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern)
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName='UseTimestamp')]
        [switch]$UseLocalTime #defaults to UTC
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName='DoNotUseTimestamp')]
        [switch]$ExcludeTimestamp #defaults to include the timestamp (as that's why we're using this function over the standard write-verbose

    )
    begin {
        [string]$FormattedMessage = '{0}'
        if(-not $ExcludeTimestamp.IsPresent) {
            $FormattedMessage = "{1:$TimestampFormat}: $FormattedMessage"
        }
    }
    process {
        #get the time here rather than in begin as we want it to be accurate per message from pipeline
        [DateTime]$Now = Get-Date
        if(-not $UseLocalTime.IsPresent){$Now = $Now.ToUniversalTime()}
        #determine output back to original stream
        [bool]$outputStream = $true
        if($InputObject.WriteErrorStream)  {$outputStream=$false;write-error   ($FormattedMessage -f $InputObject, $Now)}
        if($InputObject.WriteWarningStream){$outputStream=$false;write-warning ($FormattedMessage -f $InputObject, $Now)}
        if($InputObject.WriteVerboseStream){$outputStream=$false;write-verbose ($FormattedMessage -f $InputObject, $Now) -Verbose}
        if($InputObject.WriteDebugStream)  {$outputStream=$false;write-debug   ($FormattedMessage -f $InputObject, $Now) -Debug}
        if($outputStream){$InputObject}
    }
}

#demo
1..20 | %{
    if($_ % 2 -eq 0) {Write-Output  $_}
    if($_ -eq 11)    {Write-Error   $_ -ErrorAction Continue 2>&1} #bit of a hack required to get error output to flow further along the pipeline.
    if($_ -eq 13)    {Write-Warning $_}
    if($_ -eq 15)    {Write-Verbose $_ -Verbose}
    if($_ -eq 17)    {Write-Debug   $_ -Debug}
} *>&1 | Write-Custom
```